# Compressing folder on aws instance creates a duplicate

Tags: amazon-ec2, compression

I have a web app in this path

```
var/app/current
```

I use this command to zip everything including hidden files like htaccess

```
zip -r yourfile.zip * .*
```

It generates the zipped file which contains the web app files and folders in addition to a folder named current which contains another copy of the web app files and folders.

How can I compress web app files and folders including hidden files without including the directory named 'current' as a duplicate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may not use `.*`, because that shell glob will also match `.` and `..` (current and parent directory), causing the behaviour you described.

But it isn't necessary anyway, you can just use the `zip -r` option on its own. Let me quote the manual page `man zip`:

```
   -r
   --recurse-paths
          Travel the directory structure recursively; for example:

                 zip -r foo.zip foo

          or more concisely

                 zip -r foo foo

          In this case, all the files and directories in foo are saved  in
          a zip archive named foo.zip, including files with names starting
          with ".", since the recursion does not use the shell's file-name
          substitution  mechanism.  If you wish to include only a specific
          subset of the files in directory foo and its subdirectories, use
          the  -i  option  to specify the pattern of files to be included.
          You should not use -r with the name  ".*",  since  that  matches
          ".."   which will attempt to zip up the parent directory (proba‐
          bly not what was intended).

          Multiple source directories are allowed as in

                 zip -r foo foo1 foo2

          which first zips up foo1 and then foo2, going down  each  direc‐
          tory.

          [...]
```

So you just specify the folder you want to zip, like:

```
zip -r yourfile.zip /var/app/current
```

Or if your current directory already is `/var/app/current`, just:

```
zip -r yourfile.zip .
```